# jsf html tag inside value

Tags: html, jsf-2, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've this commandButton, and I need to add a icon using Bootstrap 3.

```
<h:commandButton  id="logoutButton" action="#{loginController.logout()}" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px;" value="Log Out"></h:commandButton>
```

the icon is in a span tag for bootstrap 3 reasons, so I've tried to add it to the value property in the command button like this:

```
<h:commandButton  id="logoutButton" action="#{loginController.logout()}" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px;" value="<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log Out"></h:commandButton>
```

I've got an error, I suppose that I can't add html tags inside the value property, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't put markup in the `value` attribute of a JSF component. You should put markup in the tag body like as in normal HTML. However, this is not supported by the `<h:commandButton>` (for the very simple reason because it generates an `<input>` element and any children would end up in invalid HTML). It would be rendered *after* the generated `<input>` element.

Just use `<h:commandLink>` instead. Whilst it generates an `<a>` element, the Bootstrap CSS also just [supports](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons) it as well as to the `btn` style class.

```
<h:commandLink id="logoutButton" action="#{loginController.logout}" styleClass="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log Out
</h:commandLink>
```

*(note that I fixed the wrong `class` attribute to be `styleClass`)*

Answer (score 1):

I assume you get a parse error. This is so as the `value` attribute does not expect to contain any html code. Instead wrap your bootstrap code by the button like this:

```xml
<h:commandButton id="logoutButton" action="#{loginController.logout()}" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px;" value="Log Out">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
</h:commandButton>
```

Which generates the html output (which does not validate, see note below):

```
<input id="j_idt5:logoutButton" type="submit" name="j_idt5:logoutButton" value="Log Out" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
</input>
```

#### UPDATE

Bootstrap requires you to have a `<button>` apparently. It won't be styled correctly with an `<input type=button>`, so you have to create a custom component to add a `<button>` to the the JSF tree as JSF does not provide by default such a component. You could leverage on the code produced inside primefaces. They provide a `button` component but unfortunately it won't fit your need as they already include their own content and styles.

Classes of interest in primefaces:

- [Button component](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/3.5/org/primefaces/component/button/Button.java/) (v. 3.5)
- [Button renderer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/3.5/org/primefaces/component/button/ButtonRenderer.java)

NOTE: Actually I checked the [input element specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) and it may not host content. To be valid (and styled correctly in this case) you need a `<button>`.

Comment: your code works, but I want the icon, inside the button, where the text log out is, I know this is possible with html code, but for JSF I need the span inside the value, where the text of the button is, as you can see in this example in bootstrap: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples)