# Adding element to commandButton value

Tags: jsf, icons, commandbutton

I want to create such button in JSF.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i> 
  Save
</button>
```

But `h:commandButton` only allow to set the value of the button in attribute called "value". So I tried to create my button like that:

```
<h:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" value="<i class='fa fa-check'></i>Save" action="#{bean.save}" />
```

And got the error:

> Error The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "h:commandButton" must not contain the '<' character.

How can I embed HTML in h:commandButton?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsf html tag inside value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146515/jsf-html-tag-inside-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use like this

```
    <h:commandLink  style="width:20px;height:15px;" action="#{bean.smethodName()}"
      <i class="fa fa-searchfaicon2x"></i>                                    
    </h:commandLink>
```

Same for button

```
<h:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" action="#{bean.save}">
<i class='fa fa-check'></i>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: @nrofis Gr8 to Hear enjoy

Comment: as could be seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146515/jsf-html-tag-inside-value